# Matlab script for reading a text file is not compatible with Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

To import data from a text file I use a script in MATLAB. I want to run the same script in Octave but then I get an error.

An extract of the text file that I want to read looks as follows:

```
Rotation angle  Measured distance
-0,342  0,000
-1,440  0,000
-10,422 0,000
-11,574 0,000
-21,060 0,000
-21,528 0,000
-30,402 0,000
```

The following code is reading the text file:

```
filename = 'C:\Users\marci\Desktop\Stackoverflow\S4P1_Logfile_160419_1345.txt';   
delimiter = '\t';
startRow = 3;
formatSpec = '%s%s%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
fclose(fileID);
```

That is the error message that I get in Octave.

```
error: textscan: unrecognized option 'texttype'
error: called from
    test at line 35 column 11
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the option? Write just dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`texttype` is not one of the recognized properties for `textscan` in Octave, see https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/textscan.html.

By looking at the [MATLAB documentation for `textscan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#namevaluepairarguments), it looks like `texttype` doesn't do much anyway:

[image]

I would suggest removing it altogether from the function call. It should just work.

Comment: As you suggested I removed 'TextType' and 'string' from the function call and now it is working. Thanks for your help.